# How to give dependencies in manifest files?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rosdep, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i am new in ROS , sorry , maybe it is easy question!  can we set dependencies address in manifest files? i want to built rgbdslam package and have problem to dependencies ,i have all dependencies but rosdep can't install dependencies or locate it ,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11604/how-to-give-dependencies-in-manifest-files?/) by [ehsanghasemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1225/ehsanghasemi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ehsanghasemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1225/ehsanghasemi/) on 2011-10-25**:
i want to run rgbdslam on ubuntu 11.04 . and i download all dep files but ros could not make them!! and have error about dep files

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-20**:
Could you please be a litte more specific? What kind of dependencies? You are talking about rosdep, so I assume you mean system packages and nor ros packages? Which packages exactly? Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? Also, is it really an error message or just a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer is in [this Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#First-order_package_dependencies).

I recommend working through at least the [Beginner Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) before trying to use ROS.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ehsanghasemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1225/ehsanghasemi/) on 2011-10-20**:
i know that and i read , i have dependencies but ROS can't find them!!! i want to set dependencies address but how???

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-16**:
It sounds like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set correctly.   I suggest that you review the other Tutorials linked by @joq